# Netatalk on arch linux gives error --enable-fhs common not found

Tags: archlinux, timemachine

I am trying to install Netatalk on my arch linux arm running on my raspberrypi 3. While executing makepkg it displays following error:

> --enable-fhs common not found

I was following the instructions on this forum question https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=518 on how to install Netatalk. Any idea how to fix this?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated, even other packages that could enable a part my server to be used as time machine for my Mac......

Comment: You'll need to provide the exact error message you received, plus the exact PKGBUILD you used. Nothing in that (outdated) link should have the effect you mentioned, and it's unclear why you're editing anything at all. Moreover, what is --enable-fhs "common"? Do you mean "command"?